# tinyMCE - tinymce-rails - asset precompile woes

Tags: tinymce, asset-pipeline

I am really stumped by how to deploy tinyMCE. Precompile on it fails and so I get the
We're sorry, but something went wrong. - error.

I tried using tinymce-rails gem but just couldn't get it to work even in development by following all the instructions on the github page exactly. Wish there was a slightly verbose manual. I particularly couldn't get the partials with formbuilder code to work with it.

I think if I simply copy tinyMCE original js code to public/javascripts/tinyMCE and have enginx serve the static files it should work but I still need it in development and couldn't get rails to work with it that way. Still the roadblock is the precompile error from capistrano which causes the above error.

I even tried tinymce-hammer but couldn't get it to work either. Is there a single file, simple rich text editor?

I have to get this done today and so I am scrambling.

I would welcome any solutions...but please include as much detail, or urls. Thanks a bunch.